# Log in to a website with Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to log into http://www.qualtrics.com/login/ and then save a cookies file but it won't work.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
opener.addheaders =[('Referer', 'http://www.qualtrics.com'),
('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0'),
                        ('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')]
url = 'http://www.qualtrics.com/login/'
data = {'method' : '1', 'login' : 'my-username', 'password' : 'my-password'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(data))
res = opener.open(req)
```

But the response is what someone without account would see (it's not working).
Any help? Also, the cookies file should look like this:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
value / value / value etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this seems a little broad wouldn't [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) provide you with a good base to start from. There are a lot of good examples to pull from. Stealing from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918735/error-trying-to-login-to-webpage-using-selenium-with-python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.example.com')
browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('myusername')
browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('mypassword')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('welcomeLoginButton').click()
cookies = browser.get_cookies()
```

You may need to put some wait statements in there but there are lots of examples here on Stack Overflow and lots of info [in the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org)

EDIT:
Fixed link to the documentation.

- The find_element_by_name can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=find_element_by_name#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_name).
- More info on cookies can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html?highlight=get_cookies#cookies). For this example the cookies object is just a dict of { name:value }

Comment: Hmm, I don't know it this would work for me. Does it save the cookies in a file? I need to post something else to the website after logging in. I don't know if I explained it well.

Comment: @Slick This is interesting where can I find the docs where "find_element_by_name" and such the main api doesn't seem to list these.

Comment: @TommyDDD link should be fixed now.

Comment: @JohnJohnson Added links with some more info about the cookies. In this example the cookie just exists in memory under the cookies object. You can read and write that out to a file if you want.

Comment: @Slick Can I generate a Netscape cookie file using that? Sorry, your answer is good but I need to log into the website, then upload something so I need to stay logged in. I'll read Selenium's docs and see if I can do it. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnJohnson, try searching StackOverflow as well. This example might be what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting library called `mechanize`. It is not very up-to-date, but it works fine.

You'd have something like this:

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("http://www.example.com")
browser.select_form(name="myform")
browser["username"] = "username"
browser["password"] = "password"
browser.submit()
```

It does all the cookie automation for you (although you can override that behavior). You'll also likely need to add headers (referrer, user-agent, etc.).

The library is available here: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

EDIT: Their (admittedly poor) documentation also explains how you can save/manipulate cookies.